# How to conditionally enable/disable filter in web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring MVC. I have a `web.xml` and a `myapp.xml`. In the `myapp.xml` I'm taking advantage of the spring beans profile. So, I've got two profiles `dev` and `test`. Each has different beans that get initiated based on the environment variable.

I'm wondering if something similar can be done in `web.xml`? In web.xml I've got the following which I only want to enable when the environment variable is `test`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling/disabling a web.xml filter using a Spring profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800916/enabling-disabling-a-web-xml-filter-using-a-spring-profile)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case you already use `DelegatingFilterProxy` that delegates actual processing to a Spring bean named `springSecurity`.

So, you need to replace your Spring Security configuration with a no-op implementation of `Filter` declared as `springSecurity` in your `dev` profile.

Comment: For now I've been completely commenting out this filter in web.xml when in dev mode and then everything works fine. can you please elaborate on no-op implementation?

Comment: An implementation that simply calls `chain.doFilter()` in its `doFilter()` method.

Comment: So, I would create a no-op implementation of `Filter`, say `MyFilter`, and initiate this as `springSecurity` in the `dev` profile as `<bean id="springSecurity" class="com.somepackage.MyFilter">`?

Comment: You could also make `MyFilter` create a filter based on some criteria and let that instance handle the filtering. [Here's an example using the ConfigurableSitemeshFilter](https://github.com/sitemesh/sitemesh3/blob/master/sitemesh/src/main/java/org/sitemesh/config/ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java) which is part of Sitemesh 3

Answer (score 3):

You can use property variable substitutions in web.xml (and server.xml):

```
<url-pattern>${urlPattern}</url-pattern>
```

Where you would pass in a **JVM** argument like `-DurlPattern="/"`

You can use **o/s** environment variables, like this:

```
set "CATALINA_OPTS=-DurlPattern=%SOME_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE%"
```

in `bin/setenv.bat` (you need to create this file). Similar functionality in *nix.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. `web.xml` is a very static format.

The usual workaround is to install a filter that delegates to an injected bean and then replace this bean using profiles.

Comment: How would that custom filter look like? can you please point me to some examples?