# Enabling/disabling a web.xml filter using a Spring profile

Tags: spring, web.xml, spring-profiles

I have a Spring application that can use two different persistence API:

- Spring Data JPA
- Spring Data Neo4j

When using Spring Data JPA, I need to declare the "OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter" in "web.xml" to do lazy loading:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The problem is that I cannot keep this filter enabled when using Spring Data Neo4j. Leaving it enabled leads to the following runtime error:

```
No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
```

I want to choose which database to use with a Spring profile (e.g. `spring.profiles.active=relational-database` or `spring.profiles.active=graph-database`).

**Question**: how can I enable the "OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter" when profile is "relational-database", and disable it when profile is "graph-database"?

Thanks!

Related questions :

- [How to conditionally enable/disable filter in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831498/how-to-conditionally-enable-disable-filter-in-web-xml) but I'm not using `DelegatingFilterProxy`.

Comment: You cannot as the web.xml has nothing to do with Spring. You could by using the solution from the question you linked to and in the case of not needing it using a dummy filter instead of the actual filter.

Comment: The idea would be to create my own "no-op" implementation of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` and load it only when profile is "graph-database"?

Comment: No just create a noop implementation of a filter that is enough it doesn't have to be a specific one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I sorted this out. My new "web.xml" uses `DelegatingFilterProxy` instead of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>toggleOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>toggleOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then in my ApplicationContext, I create a bean named "toggleOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter" (which is the `filter-name` value). The trick is to instanciate a different class depending on the Spring profile:

```
<beans profile="graph-database">
    <bean id="toggleOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter" class="my.project.dal.utils.spring.DoNothingFilter"/>
</beans>
<beans profile="relational-database">
    <bean id="toggleOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter"/>
</beans>
```

The `my.project.dal.utils.spring.DoNothingFilter` is defined as:

```
public class DoNothingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

This seems to work.

Comment: Future readers: in case you're using an old version of Spring, having two `<beans>` elements nested in a single root `<beans>` node (and `profiles` for that matter) requires Spring 3.1, and in the XML file the namespace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd`.