# spring boot - disable quartz scheduler

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, quartz

I need to be able to set up quartz to run depending on the profile. I am using an integration test to make sure that each profile is getting the scheduler started (or not), but I am checking a profile that doesn't have it enabled and this check is failing:

```
assertFalse(scheduler.isStarted());
```

This is what I have used for this profile in `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  quartz:
    enabled: false
```

Also tried:

```
spring:
  quartz:
    properties:
      enabled: false
```

Any ideas how to get quartz to not start at all?

As a workaround, is it possible to set up a dummy scheduler on the profile so that *the real quartz* is skipped altogether?

PS I have noticed this, but I'd like to keep it in application.yaml if at all possible: [How to disable Quartz scheduler for dev and stg environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808664/how-to-disable-quartz-scheduler-for-dev-and-stg-environment)

Comment: For a list of properties, see org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzProperties

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this worked:

```
spring:
  quartz:
    auto-startup: false
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, disabling `spring.quartz.auto-startup` wasn't enough. Quartz was still happily starting and reporting so in the logs:

```
org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl    : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
(...)
org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@4560eb15
```

I had to add:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { QuartzAutoConfiguration.class })
```

to the

```
@SpringBootApplication(...)
```

...to get rid of it.

**Update:** Version is Spring Boot v2.7.7, Spring v5.3.24.

Comment: I also had to exclude the `TraceQuartzAutoConfiguration.class`