# Need to Register a 3rd Party Filter in Spring MVC (Not Spring Boot) for a particular profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, servlet-filters

I have to register a custom 3rd part non Spring Filter in my Spring MVC application (Not Spring Boot) ,

The only approach which is see is adding the filter tag in web.xml file something like

```
<filter>
//Add custom filter class and other properties like order .. 
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
//Add url pattern
</filter-mapping>
```

The problem with this approach is that I want this filter to be invoked only when a specific spring profile is set . In other words I want a class which can be annotated with @Profile("staging") to register the filter as spring beans .

In Spring Boot I saw we can do it using the FilterRegistrationBean to register the filter and mark the class with Profile annotation .

Is there any such way I can do it in Spring MVC as well . I have been searching an optimal solution for this from the last couple of days but could not find much information .

The solution regarding using the Profile annotation will be very helpful to make the project consistent as all the other things related to that environment are also written using the Profile annotation .

Edit1 :

Spring boot way :

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<ThirdPartySecurityFilter> securityFilterFilterRegistrationBean() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean<DMPSecurityFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    final ThirdPartySecurityFilter thirdPartySecurityFilter = new ThirdPartySecurityFilter();
    registrationBean.setFilter(thirdPartySecurityFilter);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/rest/v2/*");
    registrationBean.setOrder(1); //set precedence
    return registrationBean;
}
```

The above is want I want to achieve in Spring MVC

Comment: Have you tried declaring the filter as a `@Bean @Profile("myProfile")`? It should get picked automatically by Spring MVC

Comment: But then how do i set the order of the filter and the url pattern ..

Comment: If you need a customized config, you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30806487/1092818)